# How to include a nested PropertyBusinessObject in a PropertyBusinessObject json?

Tags: codenameone

My app contains several `PropertyBusinessObject` entities, and most of them have nested `PropertyBusinessObject` objects as properties.

For instance, a `Note` has a parent `User` which had written the note, so the `Note` entity contain a `Property<User, Note>` which is instantiated with the `User.class` and the name of the property.

Here is the code of the `Note` Entity:

```
public class Note extends AbstractEntity 
{
    public final Property<User, Note> author = new Property<>("author", User.class);

    public final Property<String, TarotNote> text = new Property<>("text");

    public Note() {}
}
```

`AbstractEntity` implements the `PropertyBusiness` interface and define the methods to be overridden by the entities to properly implements the interface.

And here is the result JSON from `PropertyIndex.toJson`:

```
{
  "author": "our.app.backend.entity.User@77203809",
  "text": "test"
}
```

Do I need to override the `toString` method of all my entities to be sure to not have this behavior (seems to be the wrong way...) ? Or (I hope) is there another way?

For your information, the parsing of the Json issued from the server works perfectly fine with nested entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a logic bug in the JSON generation code, I've added code to fix this here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/34447f62971d8bb696116f02c97bac9b70de89b6

Comment: Thanks for the fix ! Update next friday I suppose ?

Comment: Yes this Friday (November 9th 2018)